# Removing Collection Parent Elements From WSDL using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a SOAP web service which will be self-hosted using WCF.  The schema of the web service is dictated by a client, and cannot be changed.

Here is my web method (simplified for the sake of explanation):

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/")]
public interface IOrderService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SendOrder(string Name, Order[] Orders);
}

public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    public void SendOrder(string Name, Order[] Orders)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

And here’s the Order class it uses:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/")]
public class Order
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that the SOAP body needed to call this web service looks something like the following:

```
<exam:SendOrder>
  <exam:Name>John Doe</exam:Name>
  <exam:Orders>
    <exam:Order>
      <exam:Number>1234</exam:Number>
      <exam:Item>iPhone</exam:Item>
    </exam:Order>
    <!-- More orders go here -->
  </exam:Orders>
 </exam:SendOrder>
```

But I need to remove the “Orders” tag, to make a flatter structure as follows:

```
<exam:SendOrder>
  <exam:Name>John Doe</exam:Name>
  <exam:Order>
    <exam:Number>1234</exam:Number>
    <exam:Item>iPhone</exam:Item>
  </exam:Order>
  <!-- More orders go here -->
</exam:SendOrder>
```

I’ve been unable to find a way to do this.  If the array of orders were a field in a class (instead of a parameter in a web method), I could  mark it with an XmlElement attribute and use an XmlSeralizer to get the result I need.  But that approach doesn’t work for web method parameters.

Is there any way to get .NET to create a web service which implements the flatter schema above?

Comment: The orders property must be an array in your class.  It is no shown.  You need to put an [XmlElement] above the array.  XmlSerialization defaults to adding two tags for an array (in your case Orders and Order).  Putting [XmlElement] above the array will generate only one tag.

Comment: Thanks jdweng.  Which class do you mean?  My array only appears in the signature of my web method; where else should it go?

Comment: The fix needs to be in the SendOrder class.  There should be a property Order[] Order {get; set;} (or plural)  You need to put above the property [XmlElement]

Comment: SendOrder is a web method not a class. Are you suggesting a new class needs to be created?

Comment: Yes.  Then all you would have to do is serialize the class.